# force JQuery $(document).ready to wait for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch, es6-promise

So I am having some trouble assigning a variable to the response of a fetch request. I essentially want to run a fetch request to my API, which will return a value. I then want to assign that value to an element within the html.

When I run what I have, I can see that the value is being assigned as `Promise {<pending>}`

A few solutions I have seen is that I could run multiple `$(document).ready(function(){});`'s but I think it is still not resolving the promise before moving onto the next `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Here is what I have so far

```
            var bal;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function getCookie(name){
                    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
                    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
                    if(parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
                }
                var decoded = jwt_decode(getCookie("JWT"));
                console.log(decoded.email);
                const url = "http://localhost:3001/wallets/" + decoded.email;
                bal = fetch(url).then((resp) => {
                    return resp.json();
                }).then((data) => {
                    console.log(data[0].balance);
                    return data[0].balance;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
                $(document).trigger("my-event");
            });
            $(document).on("my-event", function(){
                    console.log(bal);
                    console.log(parseFloat(bal));
                     var oMain = new CMain({
                                    win_occurrence:30,        //WIN PERCENTAGE.SET A VALUE FROM 0 TO 100.
                                    slot_cash: 100,          //THIS IS THE CURRENT SLOT CASH AMOUNT. THE GAME CHECKS IF THERE IS AVAILABLE CASH FOR WINNINGS.
                                    min_reel_loop:0,          //NUMBER OF REEL LOOPS BEFORE SLOT STOPS  
                                    reel_delay: 6,            //NUMBER OF FRAMES TO DELAY THE REELS THAT START AFTER THE FIRST ONE
                                    time_show_win:2000,       //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF THE WINNING COMBO SHOWING
                                    time_show_all_wins: 2000, //DURATION IN MILLISECONDS OF ALL WINNING COMBO
                                    money:bal,               //STARING CREDIT FOR THE USER
...
```

I am still a little confused about how promises work and how to forcefully make things wait for them to resolve.

Comment: bal will always be a promise, even when it has resolved.

Comment: how about wrapping the whole $(document).ready() thing inside another function altogether, then calling that function from the .then() of your promise? -- one way or another the .then() feature of promises means you can be certain it'll happen after the promise resolves. see e.g. [MDN on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: @Yishmeray Would this ensure that the promised is resolved before continuing ?

Comment: Yes, that's what .then() is all about! See that MDN section. Obviously there are other resources about promises, which I admit are a bit tricky. I'm certainly no master.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an update and to close this question. This is the method I ended up with to resolve the issue.

```
const finishedPromise = fetch(url).then(r=r.json()).then(data => {
    return data[0].balance'
});
```

Then within the function where I assign the value I simply used

```
money: await finsihedPromise
```